# Any Hotkey I want to register seems to already be taken

Tags: c#, registerhotkey

I am trying to register a global hotkey in Visual c# 2012, build target framework .NET3, after using http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/180436-global-hotkeys/ as a tutorial, I got the following (abbreviated) files:

1. GlobalHotkey.cs

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Windows.Forms;
   using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

   namespace barcodelabel
   {
       public class GlobalHotkey
       {
           private int modifier;
           private int key;
           private IntPtr hWnd;
           private int id;

           public GlobalHotkey(int modifier, Keys key, Form form)
           {
               this.modifier = modifier;
               this.key = (int)key;
               this.hWnd = form.Handle;
               id = this.GetHashCode();
           }

           public bool Register()
           {
               return RegisterHotKey(hWnd, id, modifier, key);
           }

           public bool Unregister()
           {
               return UnregisterHotKey(hWnd, id);
           }

           public override int GetHashCode()
           {
               return modifier ^ key ^ hWnd.ToInt32();
           }

           [DllImport("user32.dll")]
           private static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, int fsModifiers, int vk);

           [DllImport("user32.dll")]
           private static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);
       }
   }
   ```
2. GlobalHotkeyConstants.cs

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Text;

   namespace barcodelabel
   {
       class GlobalHotkeyConstants
       {
           public const int NOMOD = 0x0000;
           public const int ALT = 0x0001;
           public const int CTRL = 0x0002;
           public const int SHIFT = 0x0004;
           public const int WIN = 0x0008;

           //windows message id for hotkey
           public const int WM_HOTKEY_MSG_ID = 0x0312;

       }
   }
   ```
3. My Form1.cs

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.ComponentModel;
   using System.Data;
   using System.Windows;
   using System.Windows.Forms;
   using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
   using Microsoft.Win32;

   namespace barcodelabel
   {
       public partial class Form1 : Form
       {

           private GlobalHotkey ghk;

            protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
           {
               if (m.Msg == GlobalHotkeyConstants.WM_HOTKEY_MSG_ID) {
                   MessageBox.Show("HOTKEY PRESSED");

               }
               base.WndProc(ref m);
           }

          public Form1()
          {
              InitializeComponent();
              this.ghk = new GlobalHotkey(GlobalHotkeyConstants.SHIFT,  Keys.F10, this);
          }

          private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
              if (!this.ghk.Register()) 
              {
                  MessageBox.Show("Hotkey could not be registered");
              }
          }

          private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
          {
              this.ghk.Unregister();
          }
      }
   ```

No matter what hotkey I want to choose, it can not be registered. I tried using Hotkey Explorer from http://hkcmdr.anymania.com/ to check if the hotkey already was taken, but it only told me it was free.

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: This code has many deep flaws.  Keep looking for something better.

Comment: Hi Hans ... can you give me a hint where these flaws are so I can identify "better ways"?

Comment: Using a hash for the id is nonsense, a hash collision produces undiagnosable failure.  Just use a counter.  The pinvoke declarations are wrong, SetLastError = true is necessary to provide a decent error message when the code fails.  Not throwing a Win32Exception when a winapi call fails makes failure very hard to diagnose.  There is no hint at all that this code needs to be called from the form's OnHandleCreated() override.  Which certainly *can* run multiple times, your hotkey simply stops working when it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've wrote down your code in my VS and it worked properly. If you want to find the error, don't check a Boolean returned form API only. if it returns False, try using GetLastError API. Then you will have an error code. Refer to MSDN and get the error's description.

Comment: Thank you so very much for that hint... Turns out I tried using a window handle that did not exist at that time. After moving the "new GlobalHotkey" line to Form1_Load, it works like a charm.